# How to retrieve individual values, which are not separated by a delimiter, from a .csv file?

Tags: php, file, csv, implode

I am using `file_put_contents` function to write a variable to a file:

```
file_put_contents ( 'C:/myfiledata.csv' , $qtype, FILE_APPEND );
```

*This function is called again and again with different values of `$qtype`. So they are appended to the already present content of the file.*

So a call thrice writes the following contents, e.g.

```
WaterMelonBlueBerryBlackBerry
```

The problem is that when I read the contents of the file by the following code, the output is:

```
Array ( [0] => WaterMelonBlueBerryBlackBerry ) $qtype: WaterMelonBlueBerryBlackBerry 0 1
```

**Thing is I need to retrieve individual values from the array (or `$qtype`). Now that the values are not separated by `commas` or something, how can I do that?**

```
$file = fopen('C:/myfiledata.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  print_r($line); //check
  $qtype = implode(',' , $line );
  echo '$qtype: '.$qtype; //check
}

fclose($file);

echo "\r\n\n";

echo file_put_contents ( 'C:/myfiledata.csv', '');

echo "\r\n\n";

echo unlink('C:/myfiledata.csv'); //echo is for check
```

---

**EDIT:-** We can see that the array I get by `fgetcsv($file)` is `Array ( [0] => WaterMelonBlueBerryBlackBerry )`. Why am I not getting something like

`Array ( [0] => WaterMelon, [1]=>BlueBerry, [2]=>BlackBerry )`

**I feel that there is something wrong with the code?
Because the values are being written to the CSV file by multiple calls to `file_put_contents ('C:/myfiledata.csv', $qtype, FILE_APPEND)`, a single value being written by a single call.**

---

**EDIT:-**

[image]

Comment: Given that CSV literally stands for comma-separated values, why does your data pretend to be a CSV file when there are no commas? Where is it coming from? (Does it at least use a different character for separation at all?)

Comment: Zarah creates the file to, so the answer seems clear to me.

Comment: You can do this with regex ([example](http://regex101.com/r/oX0iA6/1)) or with a simple explode by that variable name ([example](https://eval.in/175900))

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Where it comes from: In a nutshell we read in the favourite fruit name from a user in one page (e.g. page1.php),then adds another fruit name in the next page, then another value in the third page... we write this fruit name to a CSV file (code given in a question), and then in another page (on which we will display the health benefits of the fruit), we read one fruit name from this `.csv` file and display the health benefits of that fruit.

Comment: Can you post your CSV file's raw content

Comment: @scrowler You made a mistake in the [example](https://eval.in/175900) The contents of my file are `WaterMelonBlueBerryBlackBerry` and not `Array ( [0] => WaterMelonBlueBerryBlackBerry ) $qtype: WaterMelonBlueBerryBlackBerry 0 1`

Comment: @Dagon No, the file is created by users entering values, which I write to the file by `file_put_contents()` function?

Comment: @Zarah please update your question to reflect the actual output your script produces

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky File opened in notepad++ has contents: WaterMelonBlueBerryBlackBerry I added a screenshot of when I opened it in MS Excel. You can see all the three values are appended together and residing in a single cell.

Comment: @scrowler `Array ( [0] => WaterMelonBlueBerryBlackBerry ) $qtype: WaterMelonBlueBerryBlackBerry 0 1` from the question is the actual output of the script.

Comment: @Zarah I'm confused, it sounds like you control the entire input-to-file track, why not just add commas?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans My first instinct was just to add commas, but then I thought what's the point of the `CSV` when I insert commas myself (which I could do in a `.txt` as well). But then after the answer by @narendra I tried it. Surprisingly it did show values in different cells in MS Excel, and output result:`Array ( [0] => WaterMelon, [1]=>BlueBerry, [2]=>BlackBerry )` It is because `fgetcsv($file)` considers `,` as a default delimiter. I just checked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append a comma while putting content, if you want everything comes on single line separeted by comma. Or you can append newline character examples below

```
// for comma
file_put_contents ( 'C:/myfiledata.csv' , $qtype.',', FILE_APPEND );

// for new line
file_put_contents ( 'C:/myfiledata.csv' , $qtype."\n", FILE_APPEND );
```